# Event picking in python-data supplied by clicking on the figure with the mouse-'Symbol' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling

I am working on a program that will perform the procedure on user-given data. The data, which is a list, as I implemented, will be dynamically supplied by clicking on a figure I plot with the mouse.

Here is what I wrote so far, I define n as the number of clicks, and I waht to update x and y every time I click.

```
n = 0//#clicks

y = [[0 for i in range(10)]//y[][0] store data from y-axis
        for j in range(10)]
x = [0 for i in range(10)]//data from the x-axis

def on_click(event):
    global n,x,y
    clk=[event.xdata,event.ydata]
    plt.plot(clk,[0]*len(clk),'r.')
    x[n]=event.xdata
    y[n][0]=event.ydata
    n=n+1
    print(f'CLICK! Button: {event.button}, x={event.xdata}, y={event.ydata}')
```

But here I got an error and it really puzzles me...

```
x[n]=event.xdata
TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support item assignment
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: What's an event ? If you use a library indicate which one and provide reproducible code.

Comment: @0x0fba I am using matpoltlib, here is the handbook https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html